# Why was I blocked from posting in a chat room?

Tags: discussion, support, chat, kick-mute

I was trying to get some help with javascript code and asked a question about it. The question was closed for being too localized and moved to chat to discuss it.

I posted my code and was going to explain the issue to someone and just at that moment, I was blocked from posting in the room.

here is the link to the "inappropriate content" that I posted:

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/messages/3917744/history

```
**HTML:** 

<input 
id="textBox1" 
data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox" 
value="some text here"/> 

<button id="button1" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button">foo</button> 


**JavaScript:** 

require([ 
"dojo/ready", 
"dijit/registry", 
"dijit/form/TextBox", 
"dijit/form/Button", 
"dojo/domReady!" 
], function( 
ready, 
registry 
) { 

ready(function() { 

var textBox = registry.byId("textBox1"), 
button = registry.byId("button1"); 

textBox.on("blur", function() { 
var start = this.textbox.selectionStart, 
end = this.textbox.selectionEnd;
```

Chat Room:
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript

Please give me an explaination for what happened.

Comment: Your 1st link is broken.

Comment: it works for me. you think it is accessible only by me?

Comment: You're not blocked from the room. As far as I can tell, you're still in it.

Comment: I cant post in the room for 30 mins

Comment: @Urban: you probably need 10k rep to see deleted messages.

Comment: @MozenRath: Flagging is what keeps SE clean and functional. Calling people names isn't going to help your case.

Comment: You don't like taking the constructive path, do you? "Loosers" (well, "losers" really) is not getting you any sympathy.

Comment: have you never lost temper in your life? Ok I am sorry for calling them loosers but but I don't think what they did was correct

Comment: Sure... at which point I take a step back, breath deeply and formulate my questions as cleanly as possible. Because for all intents and purposes I might have simply been misunderstood or (yes, this does happen) wrong.

Comment: I guess this is what happens when a community grows. you loose for standing up for yourselves and and win by prejudice. pple are more concerned about a single work that I used than to help me out and I actually thought I could at least raise some eyebrows here.

Comment: I guess we'll have to agree to disagree, but there is a difference between "standing up for yourself" and taking the full contact approach of "losers, clique, elitists and prejudice". You can easily make your point, stand up for yourself and perhaps even get sympathy by refraining from the latter. But well, I'll leave it at that.

Comment: I was time banned for posting some code on the wall of a chat room! explain that!

Comment: Blurry-wavey-harp-music-dream-montage: *"Hey guys, I have this JavaScript related problem that I would like some help with. It's quite a bit of code. Do you mind me asking and posting here?" "Well, perhaps you can put it in a jsFiddle? Or post it somewhere online. We'd rather have that than a large dump. Then we're glad to help"* .... Oh how wonderful the world could have been....

Comment: and I was banned for that?

Comment: Please learn the difference between "lose" and "loose".

Comment: @MozenRath - not banned, just suspended (for a short period).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't dump huge globs of code into chat, ever. Use pastebin or similar for that. You were suspended briefly because enough people said ***MY EYES .. MY EYES...*** and clicked the flag button, it's an automatic process. Don't take it personally, just ... don't do that again :)

You might have been confused with someone that was question banned on the parent site, trying to leech help from chat. In any event, just use one of the many available paste facilities.

Answer (score 12):

Your message got flagged by enough people that it was deleted automatically, so you were also suspended from chat for 30 minutes; there's a counter on [your profile](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/896663/mozenrath) that shows when the suspension is over. You won't be able to talk in any rooms until it ends. I'm not an SO mod, so I can't see the deleted message, but it takes [6 spam/offensive flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100414/how-many-chat-flags-are-required-to-remove-a-message-ban-a-user) to delete a post, so either a lot of people were confused or your post was actually offensive

Comment: so it just happened that a bunch of elitist and/or clique users happened to prejudice on me being a new user of the chat and blocked me?

Comment: Breath in....breath out... Maybe some users possibly got confused by a big dump of code instead of a chat. Not necessarily a clique, no elitists, no prejudice...

Comment: Well... what you posted was not a chat message - it was dumping a whole lot of code...

Comment: just read the post after the one I posted my code. It says "speak of the devil"

Comment: FYI, the information given after it is most likely a reasonable indicator for the motivation for their flags: *"can you imagine me pasting a huge wall of code to you and asking you why doesn't it work?
how would you respond?"*

Comment: @ bart: I was about to explain the code wall right there. but why a time ban from the room for just a thing? deleting my post was reasonable but why the ban? I can even start chattting for 30 mins by creating a room for myself with someone who is ready to help me.