# How is it possible to get more than 8 flags on a chat message?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat, flags

The first thing I saw when logging into chat was that this message had 14 flags.

[image: Screenshot]

I thought after 8 flags, a message was deleted and the owner suspended.

What gives?

Edit: Maybe my assumptions about the chat system are wrong.

Here is what seems to be the case in my experience.

- When a user flags a message, it appears as a notification for all 10K users.
- When another user flags, or a 10K user validates, the flag count is incremented.
- When a 10K user invalidates, the flag count is decremented.
- If the flag count reaches 0, the flags are removed and the notification disappears.
- If the flag count reaches 8, the message is removed, and the owner suspended.

I can't recall anything that ever showed these to be false. Do I have some of them wrong? Is this the source of the confusion?

Comment: I think if someone marks the flag invalid it'll require yet another user to mark it valid until the net score is 0 or 6

Comment: @BenBrocka Right, but how did it get to 14?

Comment: @KendallFrey: by having at least 7 of the flags being marked as invalid.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But then it would appear as 7, not 14.

Comment: @KendallFrey: Why would that be? It has been flagged by 14 people. It just hasn't reached a threshold; think of those as the number of downvotes on a post. 'invalid' flags are upvotes, and the threshold is a score of -6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was a controversial one (I didn't think it was that bad). It was flagged and counterflagged (a.k.a. "invalid") fairly evenly, so it never reached the threshold for deletion (six more flags than counter flags; see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100439/115866)), nor the threshold for being considered invalid (at least as many counter flags as flags, with a minimum of 2).

Comment: I'm quite sure that counter flags decrease the number displayed.

Comment: @KendallFrey I'm fairly sure balpha knows how the flag system on chat works, as he's one of the developers that wrote it ;-).

Comment: @KendallFrey: Perhaps you feel it should, but since Balpha is the *author* of the code, I think you should trust him a little when he tells you how it actually works. :-)

Comment: See my edit. There appears to be some misconceptions somewhere.