# If clicking "show all" doesn't remove my uncertainty then it shouldn't remove my ability to declare my uncertainty

Tags: feature-request, chat-flags

Users with 10,000 reputation are shown chat flags from across the network. The flag first appears as a blue number in the bottom corner of the chatroom. Wen you click on the number you are presented with the flagged message, as well as the choice to validate the flag, invalidate it, or be unsure about it:

[image: Screenshot of flagged message with options]

If you click on the "show all" link contained in that popup you get taken to a new page which lists all current chat flags. However, in this location you only have two options, You can agree with the flag or disagree with it, but you can no longer be unsure about it:

[image: Screenshot of "show all" tab]

As far as I can tell, there is no additional information contained in that page that would make someone more certain than before. Thus, there should still be the option of choosing that you are unsure.

This is not just a nitpicky request for the sake of aesthetic conformance. As per [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100414/how-many-chat-flags-are-required-to-remove-a-message-ban-a-user/100439#100439), the "not sure" option has it's own weight. It counts as 1/5 of an "invalid" choice. Thus, removing that option can actually affect how flags are processed. As such, the "show all" page should be revised to include the "not sure" option as well.