# Random User-Pinging in Chat

Tags: discussion, chat, ping

So I'm a chat regular, and today somebody came into chat and asked a question. When he didn't get an answer, he started pinging random people in the room (which I would find very annoying if somebody did to me, so I told him to stop). Well, okay, that annoyed me but at least he didn't do it again. Now I come back a few hours later and he pings people when they *join* and asks for help. I mean, come on, even users that haven't ever talked on chat before.

So am I just being really paranoid or is there an issue with this? If so, what should I do next time the situation arises?

[image: chat transcript]

<sup><sub>Sorry if this came off as a rant, but I don't really know how to deal with this situation.</sub></sup>

Comment: Depends. Is it a gallery chat room? Then remove his access. If not, maybe you could flag for moderator attention.

Comment: Would that be acceptable? (as in, it wouldn't be a total overkill to flag for a mod?) And no, it's a public chat room

Comment: Eh, not sure. Never done it before... I mean, if the person is that bothersome... the only way to deal with it is chat-bans.

Comment: Yeah.. it'd be useful if chat room owners had a bit more power, but I suppose that's another issue

Comment: That would be nice... I'm pretty sure there's a question on that here, give me a sec. Aha! [Moderation controls for Public Chat Rooms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90228/moderation-controls-for-public-chat-rooms)

Comment: @hichris123 Hmm, interesting question. Although sadly nothing was ever done about it :( nonetheless, in situations like this, it would be convenient for owners to have kick powers and such.

Comment: I believe this solved with this: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/15432971#15432971

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Flag for moderator attention and explain the issue, a moderator can suspend a user from chat if they're being disruptive. And pinging random people in chat is rather disruptive.

Comment: This seems to be the general consensus of what to do in this type of situation, so I'll go ahead and mark it as the answer. If anyone else has any thoughts/comments, please chime in.