# You cannot kick suspended users

Tags: support, flags, chat, account-suspension, kick-mute

In the past few minutes [a user](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/3111737/sakhal-turkaystan) posted the same message in almost every SO chat room. They had generated about 14 flags before they came into our room. Upon entering, they posted the same spam message as in the other rooms.

When I tried to kick-mute the user, I got this message: "You cannot kick suspended users" which is one of the stipulations in @balpha's answer here :https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239226/178816 under "Who can be kicked?"

> The kickee is not suspended.

However, one of the parts of the kick-mute system, as stated in the same answer is

> They will drop out of the "who's here" list, and they will be redirected to a page that (almost precisely) contains the message that Shog9 suggested. They will also be shown this page if they try to re-enter the room.

At this point, the user noted above has been suspended from chat for a month. And yet, they are still in the room which led me to some confusion.

Is this because they were automatically suspended due to flags? Is it possible to remove this user automatically from rooms they are in when they are suspended? If I kick-mute a suspended user can it simply remove them from the room similar to if they tried to enter a room? Is this by design?

Comment: Unless the person has an offensive avatar, does it really matter that the person is still in the room? The user won't be able to talk anyway.

Comment: @Mysticial - They probably have access to a socket for the room. It is part of their suspension that they drop out of the "who's here" list. In my opinion, it does matter, and if their avatar is offensive it would only highlight the need for a process to remove them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If someone gets suspended, kicking them out of the room is almost certainly not going to be enough. In this case, this same user had done the same thing a month ago, at which point I manually increased his suspension to 30 days.

Two blatant violations is sufficient; his account has been sown with salt.

Comment: I notice that now this user is no longer currently in any rooms. Was that automated, manual removal, or did the user do that of their own volition?

Comment: I expect they were probably just being polite and considerate of others for the first time in their life.

Comment: User's main account has been nuked @Travis

Comment: It would still be nice, sometimes, to have the ability to prevent suspended users from lurking, though.

Comment: Impossible without private rooms, which is a nonstarter.