# Allow moderators to bypass kicking limitations

Tags: feature-request, chat, moderator-tools, kick-mute

In chat, there are limitations on whom a room owner/moderator can kick. Most importantly, a moderator cannot kick someone who hasn't spoken yet, this is unfavorable.

There are plenty of cases where a moderator would want to kick a disturbing element even without him having spoken (avatar spam, star spam).

Currently, there is no way to even slow down a rogue user from abusing chat features that don't require talking.

Can we give moderators the ability to kick any user in chat, as long as it isn't another moderator?

Comment: _as long as it isn't another moderator_ but what if I want to kick another moderator?  :)

Comment: Easy, ask @Shog9 to do it.

Comment: "there is no way to even slow down a rogue user from abusing chat features that don't require talking" Doesn't suspending them (from chat) work?

Comment: @Yannis Not unless you suspend them network-wise AFAIK, although I may be proven wrong.

Comment: Will this ability have a cooldown? I think it should, to prevent MODABUSE.

Comment: @Krazer just like regular kicking, first kick bans the user from the room for 1 minutes, second for 5, and third for 30 and raises a flag. Although if you reached a position where you had to kick a user twice, you'd probably manually suspend him from chat.

Comment: @Yannis - Suspending them will not remove them from the room.

Comment: Related (and in no way duplicate) http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245499/178816

Answer (score 7):

Kicking doesn't make a lot of sense for users who haven't spoken. You're muting someone *who isn't talking*.

There are other forms of abuse, of course. And moderators have tools for handling them:

- Timed suspension
- Deletion

You can't star or flag-spam a room if you're suspended. Of course, suspending a star/flag-spammer requires you to identify the culprit, but... so does kicking.

If someone is trolling a room with offensive avatars, just destroy their account. Not only does this get rid of the user, it feeds into other systems that can block *new* accounts if the person responsible decides to keep it up.

Comment: TBH, knowing who stars things is relatively simple. But kicking is a nice point between "warning" and "suspension". It's a small slap to the face that is doing wonders in the RO division. Removing a user from the room for a minute is something I'd like to be able to do, regardless of whether or not they've spoken.

Comment: Does suspending someone kick them off the userlist?

Comment: No, but destroying them does, @ɥʇǝS

Comment: A recent example shows a case where we don't want to destroy a user because we don't want him opening new accounts, and we don't want to wipe all of his history, but still have compelling reasons to remove him from chat rooms (or chat in general). Hoping this can be revisited. Kicking isn't *just* about muting. It's also about removing the user from the room for a period of time.